# send SMS automatically if the state of a button does not change for a period

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

currently I'm developing an application which involve an action to perform send SMS automatically to a person if the state of a button does not change for a period. Simply speaking, if let say there a button called send(current state = off), and i left it for 15 minutes without changing the state, the application will send sms to a person for me automatically. Note that, although the application is close or user is in homescreen, the time for the state is still counting and still able to perform the action automatically. Please help me, any references is appreciate.

Comment: I won't use this app, as it sends SMS without my consent (it costs $$$ !)

Comment: You can use Service for checking time in background. 

see this link http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=46294

Comment: There are button to disable the feature :). This feature is means to perform kind of emergency action

Answer (score 0):

Take some global variables in the activity:

```
 int time_in_minutes=15;
 Thread th;
 boolean ifPressed=false;
 boolean loop=true;
```

When you start the Activity, start a background thread:

```
th=new Thread(new Runnable()
   public void run()
   {
       while(loop)
       {
       for(int i=0;i<time_in_milliseconds;i++)
        {
           if(ifPressed)
               break;
           else
               Thread.sleep(time_in_milliseconds);
        }
    if(i==time_in_milliseconds)
         {
         sendSMS();
         loop=false;
         }
    else
        {
            ifPressed=false;
            loop=true;
        }
       }
   }
);
th.start();
```

Finally, make the ifPressed variable true when you press the send button.